# positivity of the spectrum of quasi-stationary signals

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, fourier-series, random-process

I am working on the "System identification : theory for the user" by Lennart Ljung (freely available [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwisgfT59Ib-AhVPT6QEHUrxBdgQFnoECCMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mit.bme.hu%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Foktatas%2Ftargyak%2F9132%2FLjung_L_System_Identification_Theory_for_User-ed2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2HrPzAZbx3g2OgZZoFhU67)) and it is one of these books which contains exercises but no answers... My exercise is the 2G2 p47.

The context is as follows :

s is a discrete scalar real quasi-stationary signal, a quasi-stationary signal being a stochastic signals that verifies :
$$
\exists C>0\quad\text{such that :}
$$
$$\forall t\in \mathbb{N}\quad\vert E[s(t)]\vert \leq C  \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$\forall t,r\in \mathbb{N}\quad\vert E[s(t)s(r)]\vert \leq C  \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$\forall\tau\in\mathbb{Z}\quad R_s(\tau) = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^{N}E[s(t)s(t-\tau)]\quad\text{exists}\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

We assume the spectrum exists. In this context it is defined as :

$$\Phi_s(\omega) = \sum_{\tau=-\infty}^{+\infty}R_s(\tau)e^{-i\omega\tau}\tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

My question bears on question **(ii)** of the following exercise :
$$
\begin{split}
&\textbf{(i) : }\quad \forall\omega\in\mathbb{R}\quad\Phi_s(\omega) \quad\text{is real }\\
&\textbf{(ii) : }\quad \forall\omega\in\mathbb{R}\quad\Phi_s(\omega)\geq 0\\
&\textbf{(iii) : }\quad \forall\omega\in\mathbb{R}\quad\Phi_s(\omega)=\Phi_s(-\omega)\\
\end{split}
$$

Quickly, the answer for **(i)** and **(iii)** :

Remark how in \ref{eq3} the sum starts at $t=1$ so, by convention we can set $s(t)=0$ for $t\leq 0$. Then we may note that :
$$\forall N\geq 1\quad \sum_{t=1}^{N}s(t)s(t+\tau)=\sum_{k=\tau+1}^{N+\tau}s(k)s(k-\tau)$$
then via the definition \ref{eq3}, it comes easy that :

$$\forall\tau\in\mathbb{Z}\quad R_s(\tau)=R_s(-\tau)\tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

from that, by using this symmetry in the sum of \ref{eq4}, we get :

$$\Phi_s(\omega) =R_s(0) +2\sum_{\tau=1}^{+\infty}R_s(\tau)cos(\omega\tau)\tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

which instantly solves **(i)** and **(iii)**.

Now, how to solve **(ii)**? Here is what I tried :

I thought that probably $\Phi_s$ is continuous. Then if we can show that, except if $s=0$ $\Phi_s$ does not cancel then $\Phi_s$ is of constant sign. Just one evaluation (maybe $\Phi_s(0)\leq 0$?) and then we're good but I don't know how to proceed.

Another idea I had is that if I have
$$\sum_{\tau=-\infty}^{+\infty}\vert R_s(\tau)\vert < R_s(0)\tag{7}\label{eq7}$$
then I can conclude. But I cannot even show that the sum in \ref{eq7} exists. All I have is that I'm pretty sure that the relation \ref{eq3} defines a scalar product and therefore, by Cauchy Schwarz, we should get that :

$$\forall \tau\in\mathbb{Z}\quad R_s(\tau)\leq R_s(0)$$

Does anybody know how to solve this? I'm sure I missed something stupid.

NOTE : I already asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670378/positivity-of-the-spectrum-of-a-quasi-stationary-signal) in math stackexchange where it had very little success but given the question it felt legit to ask it here. I hope it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since the power spectrum is the DTFT of the auto-correlation function, we have

$$R_s[n]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\Phi_s(\omega)e^{jn\omega}d\omega\tag{1}$$

Since $R_s[0]$ equals the power of the the process $s(t)$, it follows that

$$R_s[0]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\Phi_s(\omega)d\omega\ge 0\tag{2}$$

We can define a new process $\tilde{s}(t)$ which is a bandpass filtered version of $s(t)$ with no frequency components outside the interval $[\omega_1,\omega_2]$. The power of $\tilde{s}(t)$ is

$$R_{\tilde{s}}[0]=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\omega_1}^{\omega_2}\Phi_s(\omega)d\omega\ge 0\tag{3}$$

where I've used the fact that $\Phi_s(\omega)=\Phi_s(-\omega)$.

Eq. $(3)$ must be true for any interval $[\omega_1,\omega_2]$, which is only possible if $\Phi_s(\omega)\ge 0$ holds.

Comment: I might be missing something but isn't the inverse DTFT supposed to be $$R_s[n] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{2\pi}\Phi_s(\omega)e^{jn\omega}d\omega$$? (note the integrale limits)

Comment: @NokiYola: You're right, I was thinking about continuous-time. Fixed.

Comment: I think you actually answered the question. I'm not sure that's what the author had in mind but unless I missed something it works. Thank you !

Comment: I was just wondering, is it ok to say that for any given arbitrary $2\pi$-periodic there is a unique associated quasi-stationary signal?

Comment: @NokiYola: I would say that for any *non-negative* $2\pi$-periodic function one can find a discrete-time process with a power spectrum that equals the given function, but I'm pretty sure that such a process is not unique.